# Laravel search exam result if a allow == true or false

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel. Please excuse the newbie question but how do I find if a search script exists? I want to check when student search his number will be return true or false  if admis = true => student is allow else student is not allow.
[my table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5mfQ.png)

**Controller:**

```
    <?php
    class SearchController extends BaseController {
        public function search()  
        {   
        $inputs = Input::all();
        $text_query = e(Input::get('q'));
            
        if (UserData::where('numero', 'like', '%' .$text_query. '%')->orWhere('admis', '=', true)->first()) {
        
            return ('ADMIS');
        } 
        
        else {
                (UserData::where('numero', 'like', '%' .$text_query. '%')->orWhere('admis', '=', false)->first());
                
                return ('NO ADMIS');
            }
           
    }
    
}
```

**Views:**

```
<!-- Search Bar -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{ Form::open(['route'=>'users_data', 'method'=>'GET'])  }}
            <div class="intro-banner-search-form margin-top-95">
                <!-- Search Field -->
                <div class="intro-search-field with-autocomplete">
                    <label for="autocomplete-input" class="field-title ripple-effect">Résulats en ligne...</label>
                    <div class="input-with-icon">
                     @if(Input::has('q'))
                            {{ Form::text('q', Input::get('q'), ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'autocomplete-input']) }}
                      @else
                      {{ Form::text('q', '', [ 'placeholder'=>'Saisir ici votre numéro d\'inscription', 'class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'autocomplete-input']) }}
                     @endif
                        <i class="icon-line-awesome-sort-numeric-asc"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="intro-search-button">
                    <button class="button ripple-effect" onclick="window.location.href='freelancers-grid-layout-full-page.html'">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
             {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you so much for your helping.

Comment: Your question, has no questions, you are just stating what you are trying to do. What is the problem you can't solve?

Comment: Thank you to reply, my problem is how to create search by number for students but check by admis if it = true ot false,

Comment: What do you mean by "number for students", your approach seems a little weird, with a database condition deciding what you can search. Could you imagine that it is if admins exists do something or if they dont do something else?